# Ionic4: ion-datetime cancelText and doneText won't be overriden

Tags: date, ionic4

There is something wrong with the [ion-datetime component](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/datetime) where cancelText and doneText are ignored and therefor the default values Cancel and Done are always used instead.
This is both a problem when overriding them in a template or by code.
Any help would be appreciated!

```
<ion-datetime displayFormat="D MMM YYYY" mode="ios" cancelText="TEST" doneText="TEST" #date></ion-datetime>
```

Comment: Are you using ionic-angular, ionic-react or just plain ionic?

Comment: i m using ionic-angular